# TCPDF taking way longer time then FPDF

Tags: tcpdf, fpdf

I am generating a reporting using both FPDF and TCPDF for comparison sack. What I notice is FPDF took nearly 40seconds but TCPDF took nearly 3minutes and 20seconds. Any reason why so big difference among them?

Answer (score 0):

That's my experience, too. For my PDFs, TCPDF takes 7 - 10 times longer. I strongly recommend FPDF unless you need the features that TCPDF has that FPDF doesn't have. This list make be shorter than you think. See my book (free):

http://basepath.com/PDFbook